# Signalr - connecting to a remote hub from javascript client code

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, signalr

My scenario is this:

1. Server application A saves a assigned task to a database.The change in
   database is monitored by a change notification and there is a server hub running.
2. Client side Javascript code,running along with server application B, has to connect to the remote hub. so that it receives a notification whenever App A inserts into the DB.

Here is my **server code**

I had downloaded owin.cors package.

```
 [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Global))]
 namespace Demo
  {
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {


        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors=true,

            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });

    }
```

notificationHub.cs

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{

    public static Hashtable UserIdLookupTable = new Hashtable(20);
    public static Dictionary<string,Job> PendingNotificationTable = new 
    Dictionary<string,Job>(20);

    public void OnChange(string userId,string task,string description,string 
     duration)
    {
        if (UserIdLookupTable.ContainsKey(userId))
        {

    this.Clients.Client(UserIdLookupTable[userId].ToString()).Notify(userId, 
   task);
            UserIdLookupTable.Remove(userId);
            if (PendingNotificationTable.ContainsKey(userId))
                PendingNotificationTable.Remove(userId);

        }
        else
            PendingNotificationTable.Add(userId, new Job(userId, task, 
    description, duration));

    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name =Context.QueryString["userId"];
        registerConnectionId(name);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public void registerConnectionId(string userId)
    {
        if (UserIdLookupTable.ContainsKey(userId))
             UserIdLookupTable[userId] =  Context.ConnectionId;
            else
                  UserIdLookupTable.Add(userId, Context.ConnectionId);

        if(PendingNotificationTable.ContainsKey(userId))
        {
            Job j=PendingNotificationTable[userId];
            OnChange(j.UserId, j.Description, j.EmployeeName, j.Duration);

        }

    }
```

**Client Side Code** connecting to the remote hub

My script includes

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/HubConnection.js"></script>
```

HubConnection.js

```
function ConnectToHub()
 {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $.connection.hub.url = "http://myip:56698";
   $.connection.hub.qs = { 'UserId' : '35' };
   var connection = $.hubConnection();
  var hub = connection.createHubProxy('NotificationHub');
  hub.on('Notify', function(userName, message) {
     console.log(userName + ' ' + message);
   });
   connection.logging = true;
   connection.start().done(function () {
        console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);

    })
    .fail(function (a)
    {
        console.log('Could not connect'+ a );
    });
    }
```

While debugging using chrome, it comes to connection.start and does not go in to success or fail.Just leaves the script.There is no sign that it has connected to the server.

It has to hit OnConnected on server right?

Wondering whether i have missed something.

The above client code is all i did on the client project (apart from installing signalr.client package.) Thats enough right?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing the problem or not, your hubname in javascript is capitalized, if I'm not mistaken you need to use a lowercase var hub = connection.createHubProxy('notificationHub');